# What is a solution for ajax post when I want to post a variable but have 1 js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my page I have the following code, that each `add-to-favor-` is followed by a unique `hash` to distinguish my multiple results.

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-t-10 add-to-favor-'.$active[hash].'">
    <i class="text-danger fa fa-heart"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is that I do not know how to have one universal solution for my problem. I want to pass the `active[hash]` to the ajax post.
Shall i use data-attributes? If yes, how ?

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.add-to-favor', function (){  
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: ,
            data: ,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#show_the_favor').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `data-*` attribute.

You specify data attribute as `data-some-name="value"`. To get that value use `.data('some-name')`

```
<a data-hash="<?= $active['hash']; ?>" data-target="#show_the_favor" class="add-to-favor"></a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add-to-favor', function () {
        var el = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'someUrl',
            data: {hash: el.data('hash')},
            success: function(data) {
                $(el.data('target')).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for this, will try. What if i want to change `#show_the_favor` to a class but the specific data-hash class to be displayed ?

Comment: @villoui Check updated answer. Add another data attribute with selector as value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use custom attributes. For your `<a>` elements, add the class `add-to-favor` but don't append the hash to that class. Then, add another attribute, `data-hash="' . $active[hash] . '"`:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-t-10 add-to-favor" data-hash="' . $active[hash] . '">
    <i class="text-danger fa fa-heart"></i>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.add-to-favor', function() {
    var hash = $(this).attr('data-hash');
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: "script.php", // Enter the AJAX script URL
      data: {
          hash: hash
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#show_the_favor').html(data);
        // If you want to show the hash inside #show_the_favor, replace `data` above with `hash`
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: how does the js changes with this?

Comment: thank you for this, will try. What if i want to change `#show_the_favor` to a class but the specific data-hash class to be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('body').on('click', '[class*="add-to-favor"]', function (){
    var hash = $(this).attr('class').match(/add-to-favor-([^ ]+)/)[1];
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: SomeUrl,
      data: {hash:hash},
      success: function(data) {
        $('#show_the_favor').html(data);
      }
   });
});
```

or simply use data attribute:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-t-10" data-hash="'.$active[hash].'">
    <i class="text-danger fa fa-heart"></i>
</a>
```

and get the hash using `$(this).data('hash')`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply make your own Javascript Function to do this?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-t-10" onclick="add_to_favor('.$active[hash].');">
    <i class="text-danger fa fa-heart"></i>
</a>
```

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_to_favor(hash){

  alert("pass it to your ajax: "+hash);

  $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: ,
      data: ,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#show_the_favor').html(data);
      }
  });
}

</script>
```